# Dynamic parent routes issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react application where all the routes will be loaded through different parent urls.

e.g

```
   {["/sat/", "/act/", "/gre/", "/gmat/", "/toefl/"].map((path) => (
        <Route key={path} path={path}>
          <Route element={<LoginPage />} path={'login'} />
          <Route element={<SignupPage />} path={'login'} />
          <Route
            element={<ForgetPasswordPage />}
            path={'forget-password'}
          />
          <Route element={<WelcomePage />} path={''} />
        </Route>
      ))}
```

This is working. The problem is with the navigation when hitting /signup navlink from /signin page or vice versa. I want to go to /sat/signup instead it goes to /signup. How to keep parent url and change just the child url?

Comment: @DrewReese updated it. Basically navlinks not buttons, i thought it was clear.

Comment: Where are the links you are referring to? There are no links in the code shared in your post. How you are linking to routes is where the issue is. Can you share a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @AstritSpanca When the explanation of the problem starts with "*this is working.*" and then "*the problem*" is referring to the code that isn't written in the post it's impossible to *guess* the problem as a reader.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you used href="/signup" on navigation button
I suggest you to use href="./signup" or "signup"